# Failed to resolve: com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)

Tags: android, facebook, android-gradle-plugin, facebook-android-sdk

I am using facebook sdk in my project. Facebook SDK works fine till yesterday. but today when I open my project , the build failed and shows error as follows

```
 Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApkCopy'.
   > Could not resolve com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5).
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Could not resolve com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5).
         > Failed to list versions for com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk.
            > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/android/facebook-android-sdk/maven-metadata.xml.
               > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/android/facebook-android-sdk/maven-metadata.xml'.
                  > jcenter.bintray.com
      > Could not resolve com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5).
         > Failed to list versions for com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk.
            > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jitpack.io/com/facebook/android/facebook-android-sdk/maven-metadata.xml.
               > Could not GET 'https://jitpack.io/com/facebook/android/facebook-android-sdk/maven-metadata.xml'.
                  > jitpack.io
```

I tries clean & build and also inavalidate caches .but nothing worked. Also tries some stackoverflow solutions. none of them worked for me

this my repository in build.gradle

```
 repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try removing the dependencies and re-adding them and then Clean Build the project again. Also, make sure your Studio and all Services are updated.

Comment: I think It's repository error. Right now its working . I re-added everything one by one. Thanks for your replay

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Follow the below procedure to resolve the issue:-

1. Click on `Project Structure` from the icon available in the `tool bar` above.
2. Open `Dependencies` tab.
3. select

   com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)
4. Remove the facebook dependency by clicking the minus(`-`) button on the extreme right side.
5. Now, Click on Plus(`+`) button on the right side above Minus button. Select `Library dependency`
6. Type `Facebook` on the search input box and click on the search button.
7. Choose `com.facebook.android:facebook-login`. click on `Ok`.
   Sync your Gradle.

This will resolve your issue. As it has worked for me.

Comment: i came here for answering this question. after seeing your answer i turn back as the finest answer exists..

Comment: Perfect, worked!

Answer (score 14):

Use this dependency for Facebook SDK. It will work. (Tested on Android Studio version 3.0 and above)

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.30.0'
```

Answer (score 10):

remove compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'

And add below dependency it resolve my problem

compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.26.0'

Answer (score 7):

**If your react-native version is >= 9.3.0+ you can solve this issue by just removing and adding some lines:**

```
 1)Remove this line from app/build.gradle ===>
 implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[5,6)'

 2)Add this line in app/build.gradle ===>
  implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android- 
  sdk:latest.release'

 3)Add this in android/build.gradlew 
 allprojects {
repositories {


    google()
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        // Android JSC is installed from npm
        url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
    }
   mavenCentral().  <====== Add this
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
  }
}
```

4)At the end run gradlew clean command

Comment: latest.release not everywhere it will work, everyone rests on the version of Kotlin in the application

Answer (score 7):

In the file `android/build.gradle` try to replace each `jcenter()` with `gradlePluginPortal()`

Answer (score 5):

If you are using android studio below 3.0 version then
**Try this:**
Replace the dependency `compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.26.0'`

Answer (score 4):

Try below, works perfect for me

```
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5]'
```

Answer (score 4):

try to add

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-core:[8,9)'
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[8,9)'
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the dependencies and then just re-add the dependencies one by one. Finally Clean Build the Project and it should work.

A Studio or a library update may sometimes cause this type of issue.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to Module-level /app/build.gradle before dependencies:

```
repositories {
  // You can also use jcenter if you prefer
  mavenCentral() 
}
```

Add the compile dependency you need with the latest version of the Facebook SDK in the build.gradle file:

```
dependencies { 
  // Facebook SDK Core only (Analytics)
  compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-core:[5,6)'
  // Facebook Login only
  compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[5,6)'
  // Facebook Share only
  compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-share:[5,6)'
  // Facebook Places only
  compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-places:[5,6)'
  // Facbeook Messenger only
  compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-messenger:[5,6)'
  // Facebook App Links only
  compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-applinks:[5,6)'
  // Facebook Android SDK (everything)
  compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[5,6)'
  // Audience Network SDK. 
  compile 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:[5,6)'
  // Account Kit
  compile 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:[5,6)'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Worked for me:

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:5.5.0'
```

Answer (score 2):

Release implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[5,6)' with implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:5.15.1'

Answer (score 1):

Try the below dependency. It worked for me

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
```

Answer (score 1):

Earlier I had different versions of facebook-android-sdk:[5,6) & facebook-applinks:[4,5). I made it the same version and it seems to build (facebook-applinks:[5,6)).

Answer (score 0):

1- Make a search in google like this : facebook audience network sdk download
2- Go to the first result : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/guides/adding-sdk/android
3- See the section of Manual download

[image: latest facebook sdk version]

4- You will find the latest version number (for example here : 6.0.0 or 5.11.0)
5- Add the dependency like this in your build.gradle(:app) :

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:6.2.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just go to file -> re-import gradle project if you use Intelij or Android studio. I think it's a pretty simple solution. it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue, fixed it by changing

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.30.0'
```

in app/build.gradle