# Error after adding Facebook login dependency in Android

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-gradle-plugin, facebook-android-sdk

I want to integrate my app with facebook login, but when adding below dependency and syncing Gradle:

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[5,6)'
```

I got the following errors:

```
ERROR: Failed to resolve: legacy-support-v4
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: browser
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: legacy-support-core-utils
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: media
Affected Modules: app
```

My **build.gradle** in app-level:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'}
    }
}

repositories { }

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.***************"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.github.GrenderG:Toasty:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'
    implementation 'com.gauravk.bubblenavigation:bubblenavigation:1.0.7'
    implementation 'com.tuyenmonkey:mkloader:1.4.0'
    implementation 'me.riddhimanadib.form-master:form-master:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[5,6)'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and **build.gradle** on project-level:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
        classpath 'com.getkeepsafe.dexcount:dexcount-gradle-plugin:0.8.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.31.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://www.jitpack.io" }
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I've searched a lot on google and StackOverflow and tested all the methods, but this problem doesn't fix. Please help me where is my problem.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46481942/2837815

Comment: @feridok Before asking this question, I've tested the above link, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tested some of Facebook SDK versions, suddenly in **4.26.0** version, my Gradle was successfully built.
I've checked the release note of Facebook SDK on the next version ( **4.27.0** ) and I find this:

> Modified
>   + Restructured the Facebook SDK and organized it into separate libraries/modules that can depend on one another.
>   + Moves GraphRequest.createOpenGraphObject(ShareOpenGraphObject) to ShareGraphRequest.createOpenGraphObject(ShareOpenGraphObject)
>   + Moves FacebookSDK.[set|get]WebDialogTheme(...) to WebDialog.[set|get]WebDialogTheme(...)
>   + Removes unused dimens from styles.xml
>   + Removes files only used by internal tests
>   + updates proguard files

Anyway, with the following line, my problem was solved:

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.26.0'
```

It's not good news for me to use *about 3* years ago package, but at this point, I don't have any Idea.

Answer (score 7):

First of all remove

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'}
    }
}

repositories { }
```

from your app-level Gradle file when you have repositories set in your project-level Gradle file. This causes confusion.

Use `implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:5.13.0'` instead of your dependency.

You can always check [Maven Centeral](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.facebook.android/facebook-android-sdk) for the latest version of libraries.

or

Use [Gradle, please](https://gradleplease.appspot.com/), just enter the library name you need and copy the result (don't forget to replace compile with implementation)

Comment: Thank you @feridok , but your solution does not work for me, unfortunately, I encountered this error: `ERROR: Failed to resolve: legacy-support-core-utils
Affected Modules: app`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're pointing to a library that doesn't exist.
Replace your `implementation....` with:

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[5,6)'
```

(source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/componentsdks/)

Comment: Thank you, but after adding this, I got: `ERROR: Failed to resolve: legacy-support-core-utils Affected Modules: app`

Comment: Hmmm, just making sure - you removed the old `implementation...` right?

Comment: Of course, I replaced instead of previous Facebook SDK code.

Comment: Thanks, But it didn't matter :( @sean

Answer (score 0):

As Stated in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52034414/5369727), you need to add these two properties to gradle.properties file:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```