# > Task :app:checkReleaseAarMetadata FAILED - React native

Tags: react-native

I am making a release build for my project using ./gradlew assembleRelease command but it gives me this error.

```
> Task :app:checkReleaseAarMetadata FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkReleaseAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:releaseRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[8,9).
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Failed to list versions for com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/android/facebook-android-sdk/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/android/facebook-android-sdk/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException (no error message)
```

my build.gradle

```
  ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
    minSdkVersion = 21
    compileSdkVersion = 30
    targetSdkVersion = 30
    ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
    googlePlayServicesAuthVersion = "16.0.1"
}
```

Comment: Try out these solutions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46481942/failed-to-resolve-com-facebook-androidfacebook-android-sdk4-5

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue just change the compileSdkVersion in your build.gradle file.

Open  android > build.gradle file.
Change compileSdkVersion from 29 to 30.
Change targetSdkVersion from 29 to 30.
now run again.

Comment: I already changed, but it's still not working.

I already changed, but it's still not working

   `    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 30
        targetSdkVersion = 30
        ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
        googlePlayServicesAuthVersion = "16.0.1"
    }`

Comment: @MikeyD'Narith can i know your react natve version?

Comment: here's my react version: 

react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.64.1

Comment: @MikeyD'Narith
Can you try to add this two?

 googlePlayServicesAuthVersion = "16.0.1"
    androidXCore = "1.6.0"

ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "29.0.2"
    minSdkVersion = 21
    compileSdkVersion = 29
    targetSdkVersion = 29
    googlePlayServicesAuthVersion = "16.0.1"
    androidXCore = "1.6.0"
}

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue just add mavenCentral() in repositories of your project build.gradle.
Refer to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).